# Subsetting a dataset into multiples subsets in R

Tags: r, dataset, subset

I have a data that looks something like this:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), class = "factor"), 
    Value = c(10L, 13L, 12L, 43L, 23L, 66L, 78L, 42L, 19L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

I would like to divide this dataset into multiple datasets on the basis of the ID values, i.e. one dataset that contains only ID = a, another that contains only ID = b, and so on.

How do I do this subsetting automatically in R? I understand that if the number of values in ID is less, we could just do it manually, but in case there are a lot of values under ID, there has to be a smarter way of doing this.

Comment: How do I assign these as separate data frames?

Comment: Basically, I would like to have data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6, which contain IDs a, b, c, d, e, f respectively

Comment: [Keeping data frames in a list is a much better idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/4497050) Even that is usually unnecessary due to grouping options, though which is appropriate depends on the context.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `split` function.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), class = "factor"), 
    Value = c(10L, 13L, 12L, 43L, 23L, 66L, 78L, 42L, 19L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

> df
  ID Value
1  a    10
2  b    13
3  b    12
4  c    43
5  d    23
6  e    66
7  f    78
8  f    42
9  f    19

listed_df <- split(df, df$ID)

> listed_df
$a
  ID Value
1  a    10

$b
  ID Value
2  b    13
3  b    12

$c
  ID Value
4  c    43

$d
  ID Value
5  d    23

$e
  ID Value
6  e    66

$f
  ID Value
7  f    78
8  f    42
9  f    19
```

To call on one of these just use index it with `$`.

```
sum(listed_df$f$Value)
```

You can also `lapply` a function across each of the dataframes within the list. If you wanted to sum up each Value or something you could do..

```
lapply(df_list, function(x) sum(x$Value))
```

You can also do this just by `grouping` the original dataframe by ID and then perform `summarise` operations on it from there.

Comment: Yes, split does divide the dataset into the subsets that I want. But I also need to have these subsets as separate dataframes, say data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6 that contain IDs a, b, c, d, e, f respectively. How do I do this?

Comment: I answered how you call on it. `listed_df$a` _is_ the dataframe that you're talking about.

Comment: `> class(df_list$a)
[1] "data.frame"`

Comment: Yup, I would like to do this automatically. Something like subset[i] = df[df$ID == i,]

Comment: @KennethSingh If you prefer using copy/paste and find/replace to create lots of code when a simple loop or `lapply` would do, you can put all the data frames in the list to your global environment with `list2env`. But you'll be making things harder on yourself. First set the names of the list to whatever you want the names of the data frames to be. See the [list of data frames FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207) for some discussion and examples.

Comment: Basically I should be able to write a line of code that will generate all the subsets, instead of calling them manually.

Comment: Right - what you're asking is how to do the first step automatically and all subsequent steps manually. Matt is trying to show you how to do all steps automatically.

Comment: that line of code that generates all the subsets is `split(df, df$ID)`. If you want to reference all of them and do an operation to each of them, use `lapply` against the list of dfs.

Comment: Can you help me do that? So yes, we got a list that contains all my required subsets. How do I write a for loop (or something else) that will give me something like this: for i in 1:length(listed_df) {subset[i] = lapply(listed_df, function(x) x[i])}

Comment: I am really unsure of my syntax though

Comment: you don't have to do the for loop in front of it. `lapply` is a vectorized function that will iterate through your list and apply the function you pass it. So just do `lapply(listed_df, function(x) blahblah)`

Comment: So will this work: listed_df_subset = lapply(listed_df, function(x) x[1])

Comment: But wait this will give me the first data frame in listed_df right? So 1 is hard coded here. This is my doubt - how do I make this argument under x[] to be dynamic?

Comment: You can try it yourself. x is _each dataframe_ in the list. so you're looking at the "a" df, and doing df$a[1] which pulls out the first column. So you're iterating through each df with that `lapply` call to show the first column of each df.

Comment: I think we are close but still not there yet. I am not seeing 6 different datasets using the lapply method you suggested. Maybe I am missing something? Can you please help me write a code that will automatically give me 6 different subsets without me having to call each of them manually from listed_df?

Comment: update your question to include more details with what you're trying to do to each dataframe. What you're asking for is exactly as we explained and is the best way to do it. I want to understand the bigger picture so if you can update details in the question with that information

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty easy.

```
exampleb <- subset(df, ID == 'b')

exampleb
  ID Value
2  b    13
3  b    12
```

Also, take a look at these links.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/5-ways-to-subset-a-data-frame-in-r/

https://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html